# Adding only real MAC address

Tags: powershell, active-directory, mac-address

During the course of the work day I have field techs out and about and they'll occasionally need to add a MAC address to our Wireless Access group in AD. We don't fully support them getting into AD on their own and we've been using a script to allow them to add MAC addresses the right way.
I have taken it upon myself to fully idiot-proof this thing and i'm nearly there minus one glaring issue. I can't stop them from adding MAC addresses with values greater than 'f'.

```
Write-Host "MAC Address must be entered as lowercase and without colons. EX: 14d6aa6ac9be" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $MACUserName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please Input the MAC Address of the Device to be added to AD and press Enter'
    $MACUserName = $MACUserName -replace '[\W]', ''
    If ($MACUserName.Length -ne 12 -or $MACUserName -notmatch '[A-Za-z0-9]') {
        Write-Host "MAC Address: " -ForegroundColor Red -NoNewline; Write-Host $MACUserName -ForegroundColor White -NoNewline; Write-Host " is not the correct length or contains invalid characters. Please verify MAC address" -ForegroundColor Red
        Pause
        Single-Device}
```

This is where i'm at with everything so far, obviously there is much more to this than just this section but for now this is where i live.

I'm able to get rid of any colons that might be entered in and my -notmatch section includes all possible values.

if i change -notmatch `'[A-Za-z0-9]'` to `-notmatch '[A-Fa-f0-9]'` It still lets me add fake MAC addresses with z's and whatnot. How do I go about limiting the characters this section will accept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71341957/45375) offers the best solution to your problem, using a .NET API.

---

As for **what you tried**:

`'[A-Fa-f0-9]'` matches *one* character that falls into the specified ranges, which means that *one* such character in the input string makes the expression evaluate to `$true` - even if other characters outside these ranges are present.

Therefore you must make sure that *all* characters that make up the input string fall into the expected ranges:

`-notmatch '^[a-f0-9]+$'`

Alternatively, invert the logic and look for at least one *invalid* character:

`-match '[^a-f0-9]'`

Note:

- The [`-match` / `-notmatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operators perform *substring* matching by default; therefore, in order to match the *entire* string, start and end anchors `^` and `$` are needed.
- `[a-f]` is enough to match *both* lowercase and uppercase letters, because `-match` / `-notmatch` are case-*insensitive* by default, as PowerShell is in general. If case-*sensitive* matching is desired, use `-cmatch` / `-cnotmatch`

Answer (score 4):

I think you should be able to leverage the .NET [**PhysicalAddress Class**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.physicaladdress?view=net-6.0) for this. You can create a function to parse the user's input:

```bash
function Test-MacAddress {
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string] $MacAddress
    )

    process {
        try {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                ParsedMAC = [PhysicalAddress]::Parse($MacAddress.ToUpper().Replace(':', '-'))
                UserInput = $MacAddress
            }
        }
        catch {
            Write-Warning 'Invalid MAC Address!'
        }
    }
}

Read-Host 'input mac address' | ParseMAC
```

Example of how it works:

```
PS /> Test-MacAddress 01-23-45-67-89-AB

ParsedMAC    UserInput
---------    ---------
0123456789AB 01-23-45-67-89-AB

PS /> Test-MacAddress 001122334455

ParsedMAC    UserInput
---------    ---------
001122334455 001122334455

PS /> Test-MacAddress f0:e1:d2:c3:b4:a5

ParsedMAC    UserInput
---------    ---------
F0E1D2C3B4A5 f0:e1:d2:c3:b4:a5

PS /> Test-MacAddress 00112233445z

WARNING: Invalid MAC Address!
```

**Note:** The use of `.ToUpper().Replace(':', '-')` in the function is required to make it compatible with **.NET 4.x and previous versions**.

Valid Formats from **Remarks** of [`PhysicalAddress.Parse(String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.physicaladdress.parse?view=net-6.0#system-net-networkinformation-physicaladdress-parse(system-string)):

- `001122334455`
- `00-11-22-33-44-55`
- `0011.2233.4455`
- `00:11:22:33:44:55`
- `F0-E1-D2-C3-B4-A5`
- `f0-e1-d2-c3-b4-a5`

---

Taking it a step further, we could implement a custom [argument transformation attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.argumenttransformationattribute?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) that handles the possible input strings and makes it compatible with Windows PowerShell 5.1 as well as PowerShell 7+ while validating the input Mac Addresses:

```bash
using namespace System.Management.Automation

class MacTransform : ArgumentTransformationAttribute {
    [object] Transform([EngineIntrinsics] $EngineIntrinsics, [object] $InputData) {
        if($InputData -isnot [string]) {
            return [PhysicalAddress] $InputData
        }
        return [PhysicalAddress] ($InputData.ToUpper() -replace '[.:-]')
    }
}

function Test-MacAddress {
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, Mandatory)]
        [MacTransform()]
        [PhysicalAddress] $MacAddress
    )

    process {
        $MacAddress
    }
}

@(
    001122334455
    '00-11-22-33-44-55'
    '00112233445z' # This one should fail
    '0011.2233.4455'
    '00:11:22:33:44:55'
    'F0-E1-D2-C3-B4-A5'
    'f0-e1-d2-c3-b4-a5'
) | Test-MacAddress
```